# Write a regular expression to get a substring in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I apologize for the non-descriptive title, but I couldn't think of a better one.

I am trying to write a script that parses a sub string from some file names.

So, for example, here is one such file name:

`[Anime-Koi] GJ-bu - 07 [h264-720p][A8557259].mkv-00_07_33_00001.jpg`

(This is quite obviously a screenshot from an anime.)

What I want from this name is the `GJ-bu - 07` substring.

I know very little about regular expressions so I have been scratching my head trying to come up with a regular expression to do that.

I thought that finding the inverse of an expression would be really easy so I came up with:

`'(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\]?[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)'`

Python's `findall()` for the above returns:

`['[Anime-Koi]', '[h264-720p]', '[A8557259].mkv-00_07_33_00001.jpg']`

Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to get the inverse and no matter how hard I scratch my brain, I can't come up with a regular expression that does what I need.

So, uhh, could you guys help me come up with an expression that returns `GJ-bu - 07`?

I know I could cheat and just do this:

```
f = "[Anime-Koi] GJ-bu - 07 [h264-720p][A8557259].mkv-00_07_33_00001.jpg"
reg_ex = r'(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\]?[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)'
p = re.compile(reg_ex)
l = p.findall(f)
for st in l:
    f = f.replace(st, '')
```

but that's cheating so I'd rather not do that.

Thanks for your time.

( Note: I am using Python 2.7 for this, but I have no qualms with using 3.2, though I doubt it makes a difference here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
p = re.compile('\[.*\](\s.*\s)\[.*\].*\.jpg')
l = p.findall("[Anime-Koi] GJ-bu - 07 [h264-720p][A8557259].mkv-00_07_33_00001.jpg")
print l
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (`s` is the input).

```
re.search(r'(?:^|\s)([^[]*)(?=(?:\s|$))', s).group(1)
```

It essentially means, a space followed by any number of non `[` characters, and then a space.

Comment: +1 for explanation, although I'm not sure we can assume the spaces are always there?

Comment: added checks for start or end of string

Comment: This is really nice. Very clean to. 
But yeaeh, as @Junuxx said, I can't always a space. I found an example that had an underscore instead (though I think most have a space though).
(Also, thanks for the explanation it helped!).

Comment: In this part `(?:^|\s)` replace `\s` with `[\s_]` to be spaces or underscores.  RegEx has limitations.  If you want perfect, you'll need to very clearly define your input.  It can't just figure it out, unless you give it a patern.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Umm, quick question though. In terms of results found, what is the difference between your regex and the one proposed by eyquem? They look very different but get similar results.

Comment: @eyquem's solution requires that there be something in brackets, before and after, the text you're trying to match.  They also must be separated by spaces.  Try removing `[Anime-Koi]` from the string, and that code will fail.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks mate. I hope you don't mind, but I will go accept that one simply because I think that will work better for my purposes (the substring itself is a bit unpredictable as in it can have spaces or underscores, but I can prefix or suffix a bracket pair very easily.) Thanks a lot though. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pat = '\[.+?\] *(.+?) *\[.+?\]'
reg = re.compile(pat)

ss = '[Anime-Koi] GJ-bu - 07 [h264-720p][A8557259].mkv-00_07_33_00001.jpg'

print reg.findall(ss)
```